# how to export/share NSData on swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting .dwg and .pdf files from mssql in binary string format. I can preview or share pdf ones easily but can't make it work for .dwg files. At least i need to share it because previewing .dwg files should be out of scope without third party library.

Here is my code:

```
let client = SQLClient()
    client.connect() {
        success in

        if success {
            client.execute("sql query to get binary string of a file") {
                results in

                for table in results as Any as! NSArray {
                    for row in table as! NSArray {
                        for column in row as! NSDictionary {
                            self.webView.load((column.value as! NSData) as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
                            self.shareFile = (column.value as! NSData) as Data
                        }
                    }
                    client.disconnect()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and then i can share `shareFile` with `activityViewController` but on .dwg files it appears empty.

Comment: `but can't make it work for .dwg files`. What do you mean by that? Does it crash (it wouldn't be surprising, given the amount of force casting you're doing)? Does it display nothing? We can't help you if you don't tell us what's happening or not happening.

Comment: it won't append file to share extension as pdf does it. no error no crash. What i need to do is creating a local file with .dwg extension from the mssql query result string which is a varbinary column

Comment: @fuzunspm so just write your data to a temporary file url prior to sharing it